# getting result so slow from generator return by tensorflow estimator.predict?

Tags: deep-learning

Thanks in advance for all the help.

I try to deploy a tf service. just create estimator in flask and do predict

what confused me is, after results=estimator.predict(), this loop segment always cost more than 10 seconds, like this:

```
res = []
for r in results:
    res.append(r['predict_results'].tolist())
```

I've no idea why...does anyone meet issues like this?